# Change line color of qq plot in fitdist

Tags: r

I've run fitdist and stored the results in:

```
params = fitdist( data, dist,method="mle" )
results[[i]]<-params
```

My question is when I use:

```
plot(results[[1]])
```

I get several graphics including a qqplot. I'd like to change the color of the line of the qqplot. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: The `plot.fitdist` function might contain clues to a solution, but it is speculation at the moment what package has that function (and even whether results[[1]] has class of "fitdist" for that matter). You should seek out the [r] posting regarding how to make a "great reproducible example" and take the answers to heart.

Comment: If looks as though this is part of the `fitdistplus` package. Is that correct? If so, `plot.fitdist` calls `plotdist`. The help for this function does not provide any colour arguments and `...` is described as "further graphical arguments passed to graphical functions used in plotdist". Without looking at the code, I'm not sure where these go, but have you tried `col=red`? Might be a bit obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create this graph step by step with the functions `denscomp`, `qqcomp`, `cdfcomp` and `ppcomp` also included in the `fitdistrplus` package you can influence the colors:

```
# sample dataset:
data <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)

# calculate fitting:
fitting <- fitdist(data, "norm")

# the original plot:
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(fitting)

# create it graph by graph with different colors:
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
denscomp(fitting, datacol="gray", fitcol="blue")
qqcomp(fitting, fitpch = 20, fitcol="gray", line01col ="blue")
cdfcomp(fitting, datacol="gray", fitcol="blue")
ppcomp(fitting, fitpch = 20, fitcol="gray", line01col = "blue")
```